# Can TTImageView has click event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

I subclassed TTTableMessageItem to show user response, and I want to add click event on user avatar image (I knew it is a TTImageView in TTTableMessageItemCell). How to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work it out as below:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == myImageView)
    {
        // do process
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to simple add a gesture recogniser to the view - `touchesBegan` is certainly acceptable, but gesture recognisers are somewhat simpler and probably more suited to a tap detection event.